# Accessing the input field data as table data and pull it in objet

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am creating an array object from the table format.

I have 5 columns, out of **which 4 & 5th columns are input text elements**. Whatever I modify or update, those should reflect in array object which I am constructing from table.

sample JS code is given below & eq(3) which is 4th element is returning an empty value, even if I have modified the text value in it.

```
  var json = [];
  $('#MyTable').find('tbody tr').each(function(){
// document.querySelector
var obj = {},
    $td = $(this).find('td'),
    key = $td.eq(0).text(),
    val = $td.eq(3).text();
obj[key] = val;
json.push(obj);
});
```

How to get the input value in my object construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from the input box, you would need to look for the input's ID, and then use .value on that.

What I would instead recommend is to use `<td contenteditable=true>`. This will make your table value itself editable by the user. Such a feature has been in use since IE 5.5, Safari, Firefox 3, and Opera 9, so it should be suitable for your project.